# How do I fix the Ubuntu app drawer when it will not scroll through my programs?

Tags: gnome, mouse, scrolling

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and all of the sudden I went to scroll through my programs in the app drawer and I cannot scroll down. I can use the arrow keys to go down to an application, but I cannot see which programs it is going to. This isn't a huge deal, as I can just search and grab what I am looking for. But it just makes me wonder if there is an underlying issue.

I can't seem to find another question like this, or an answer to it online. I have tried restarting and a few other basic things. But this is my first month in Linux. I love it, an am getting the hang of it, but this is strange.

Comment: This could be caused by a gnome shell extension. Try to disable all extensions and restart the shell with Atl+F2 then type r and enter.

Comment: This was the first question I had ever asked on here, and I had forgotten to reply. Sorry about that. I forget exactly what had caused it but I do remember it having something to do with shell extensions. So thank you.

Comment: I found another solution online
https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-show-applications-not-scrolling-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-from-18-04-via-19-10/ in my case, it is apparently related to the scrolling from one monitor to the other.